# How to debug Angular in prod server?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In the development environment I can debug with the Chrome source tab , but in the prod server I use the dist folder content after running `ng build --prod`. This folder contains compiled code so if there is a problem in the production I don't know how to debug to find the problem.

Is it possible to debug through the production compiled code ?

Comment: Actually it's --sourceMap. It's case-sensitive.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

**Update:**
You can try`ng build --prod --sourcemap`

For the previous versions of angular-2 this would work , `ng build --prod --sourcemap`

**For Angular 12**

```
ng build --source-map
```

**For Angular 8**

As mentioned in the comments

```
ng build --prod --sourceMap
```

Comment: I guess you mean --prod instead of --product. Yes, this work . Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Is this not equivalent to development build ?

Comment: @himanshupareek66 This is not. It uses AOT just like `prod` build. Development build has other defaults.

Comment: The current defaults for --dev vs --prod builds are defined here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: It is --source-map in Angular CLI 6.0.5
ng build --prod --source-map

Comment: just a small correction, atleast when i use it with angular8 now, its --sourceMap and not --sourcemap

Answer (score 22):

In **Angualr CLI 6** options seems to be changed as

```
ng build --prod --source-map
```

Or else you can enable source maps in angular.json by setting the sourceMap:true in production configurations

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              **"sourceMap": false,**
                 --------
```

Answer (score 9):

Debugging production build without revealing source maps can be done easily.

You just have to attach your source map from a local or remote server to your production build.

Approach and Concept:

1. Build app without sourcemaps for production deployment

   ng build YOURAPP --prod
2. Deploy production build to your webserver
3. Build app again, this time with sourcemaps option

   ng build YOURAPP --prod --sourceMap
4. Attach sourcemap in your local development environment to your production build in the F12-Development Tools in your browser

[image]

Then debug as you are used to do.
This way you can even reference sourcemaps from remote devices. For example if you are inspecting a web app on your mobile device (e.g. chrome android)
Very useful to detect platform specific behaviour for your apps.

And the best, your sourcemaps never have to be revealed on a public server. They are always kept safe in your development environment.

**Hint:**
To get to the input for the sourcemap url,
click right on the .js source file as shown here

[image]

Comment: Where do i get this option to enter the Source map URL? I dont see it in my chrome.

Comment: In the sources panel click on the js (eg. main.js). Then right click in the sources and in the popup menu you get the "Add source map" option

Comment: What's the local sourcemap url

Comment: @LeifSegen it's file:///your file name . You can also drag and drop the file into your address bar.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36204497/how-can-i-specify-a-file-source-map-after-the-page-loads-up#:~:text=You%20can%20right%2Dclick%20on,paths%20are%20accessible%20to%20Chrome.

Comment: i created the source map like u said, opened the live url in browser and sources dragged this folder, now using ctrl + p i can open the file , but on adding breakpoints in actual source code is not working

Answer (score -3):

If you are deploying on test server than do not use --prod so if error comes it will show u complete detail of error but your application will run in dev mode