# How to debug Angular 2 Typescript application in production mode?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've built a simple [Angular 2 App](https://angular-testing-123.herokuapp.com/) - for learning purposes and deploy it to Heroku, set PRODUCTION = TRUE in environment.ts but it seems like i can't add breakpoints in the chrome debugger, the web pack folder isn't shown in the Sources panel -  in the developer tools....perhaps there is a way to expose the .ts files and stay in production mode?

Comment: Why not debug using dev mode instead? which is why it does exists; to help debugging

Comment: Thanks - that's because it's going to be an inner organization app - and the client wants to be able to debug from users computers - and not from the server

Comment: Then make it dev mode

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow thanks - that's one way for sure - but perhaps there is a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800032/how-to-debug-angular-in-prod-server

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow Thanks! that's what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

use `debugger` keyword wherever you need to debug.

```
getData() {
   debugger
   // your code to get data
}
```

open up the browser developer tool then you'll see the magic

for step-in, use `F-10` key (in windows)

for continue, use `F-8` key (in windows)

for more, visit: [Seven Methods for Debugging Angular Applications](https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/methods-for-debugging-an-angular-application/)

Comment: Thanks - that's very helpful!

Comment: @RoyBarOn Please don't forget to mark as answer if it helped you

Comment: How can it help in this situation, *i can't add breakpoints in the chrome debugger, the web pack folder isn't shown in the Sources panel*? A breakpoint is set up on gibberish source code.