# Not able to debug JS error "t is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular6, minify, uglifyjs

In development mode everything working but when i'm running my angular 6 app in production mode where it's generating deploying files as shown in the screen shot.
[image]

It's throwing error shown below and can also bee seen in the screen shot above. The generated main script is trying to return `new t` where t is not a constructor.

```
main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: t is not a constructor
at main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1
at Ao (main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1)
at main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1
at new e (main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1)
at Object.Xo [as createNgModuleRef] (main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1)
at t.create (main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1)
at main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1
at e.invoke (polyfills.b134ad1096bf06acde05.js:1)
at Object.onInvoke (main.8a1f9e821b7c8c76e49b.js:1)
at e.invoke (polyfills.b134ad1096bf06acde05.js:1)
```

I have commented all the switch statements in my application. Still I'm not able to find out/debug from where it's throwing this exception.
Can anyone suggest me how I can fix/debug this problem.?
Please let me know if any other inputs required.

Comment: maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45800032/how-to-debug-angular-in-prod-server

Comment: This gave me clue to reach actual problem just before "ng build --prod --sourcemaps" started throwing memory issue. Thanks a lot @RaghavGarg. This problem was related to https://github.com/bleenco/ng2-datepicker/issues/335